# How to pull multiple terms from the same Taxonomy in View Page using contextual filters?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a multilevel taxonomy tree with products/versions.

product 1

- version 3.1.0
- version 3.1.1
- version 3.2.1

product 2

- version 5.4.0
- version 5.4.1

product 3

- version 1.0.0
- version 1.0.1

I have pieces of content that have a term reference to the product and version.

I am trying to create a View Page at that uses contextual filters on the content. The path would look like: /products/product-2/version/540

The path to in my View Page is: /products/%/version/%

After that I add a contextual filter for the first term in the path and that works. But if I have two contextual filters, one for each term in the path it does not work. The second term has depth and I am not sure if that is the issue.

I tried to create a View Page with just content referencing the version and I couldn't get that to work. So that leads me to believe it is an issue getting sub terms from contextual filters.

Is there a way to pull sub terms in contextual filters?

Comment: I just updated my question because I realized it is not an issue with have two contextual filters but an issue with the term being a child of another.

Comment: I found out the problem is not that this is a child but my versions have sem versioning. 1.0.0 and 1.0.1. Because of this it wont match the title.